# Question: Is it having been sent

Tags: grammar, questions

Can I use "Is it having been sent" for question? I know I can ask "is it sent", that's why, I thought that I can put "having been sent" instead of "sent". Is it correct?

Comment: No, that's incorrect grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"having been sent" is allowed in the gerund sense (e.g. "The email having been sent, I expect a reply soon"), but not as a participle.  You either have present progressive ("is being sent") or present perfect ("has been sent"). You can't have both.

Answer (score 1):

Not in British (or, I think, American) English.

[It is possible that it works in Indian English - I'm only guessing, but I know that Indian English makes more use of progressive forms than other varieties. None of the corpora I've consulted have any examples, for India or elsewhere, so I may be wrong.]

The normal way to express this would be "Has it been sent?"

"Is it sent?" is possible, but unusual.